# JBoss 7 stays as Starting even if it is started

Tags: eclipse, jboss, eclipse-juno

I created a node of my JBoss 7.1.1 server using this method: https://community.jboss.org/thread/221012
Also, in Server State Detector, under my server's properties, I have selected "Web port" for "Startup poller".

But my server remains as "Starting" under Eclipse Juno. But, in console, I can see:

```
[org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 2391ms - Started 168 of 248 services (76 services are passive or on-demand)
```

and I can go to my web project by entering localhost:port/MyProject under my browser. How can Eclipse monitor that JBoss is successfully launched?

After a timeout, Eclipse tells me:

```
Server JBoss Node2 7.1.1 failed to start.
```

Answer (score 1):

try to change the Startup Poller to Web Port in Server State Detector on properties of the server(double click on JBoss Server in eclipse).